# kendo chart data display with filtering

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I want to use Kendo Chart and created it as:

```
<div id="chart"></div>

    function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new { Area = "SuperAdmin", Controller = "DeviceDataUsage", Action = "DeviceDataUsageChart" })',
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                },
                sort: {
                    field: "Date",
                    dir: "asc"
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                field: "Date"
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        createChart();
    });
```

My ajax call returns the following JSON:

> [{"Date":"2022-08-01T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":32596822687},{"Date":"2022-08-02T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":36612506846},{"Date":"2022-08-03T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":33163744510},{"Date":"2022-08-04T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":33885441890},{"Date":"2022-08-05T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":34242721748},{"Date":"2022-08-06T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":27183604932},{"Date":"2022-08-07T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":24292004315},{"Date":"2022-08-08T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":24229587601},{"Date":"2022-08-09T00:00:00","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":32560544972},{"Date":"2022-08-10T00:00:00Z","Account":"0442047510-00001","ByteUsed":29415723282},{"Date":"2022-08-01T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":7153376},{"Date":"2022-08-02T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":18197239},{"Date":"2022-08-03T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":27505657},{"Date":"2022-08-04T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":26128919},{"Date":"2022-08-05T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":20523014},{"Date":"2022-08-06T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":25958925},{"Date":"2022-08-07T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":25540890},{"Date":"2022-08-08T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":18362064},{"Date":"2022-08-09T00:00:00","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":26562369},{"Date":"2022-08-10T00:00:00Z","Account":"0642341711-00001","ByteUsed":25290919}]

so, as we can see, there are data for 2 different accounts (it can be 3 different accounts or more). Data can be exist for the same date for both or not, no matter (if not, we think it ByteUsed as 0).

Now I want to display this data like:

[image]

where every bar is account name, X axis is date, Y axis is byteUsed.
How to do it? I don't understand how to set series depends on `Account` value from my JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by Account, for example, and define a series of type "column" to set the rest of the configurations. I've  also added a logarithmic scale to [this example](https://dojo.telerik.com/ANozIbEW), just to demonstrate a possible configuration, as the sample data points do not show clearly in a linear scale value axis.